# Excel: unable to delete a table row

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am running Excel (M365 version 2211) on Windows 11 version 22H2.

In my spreadsheet there is a table (named "ToDeleteFromDL")   for which I cannot delete rows.
When I right click on a cell of the table the only options I am presented is to delete the column (which I don't want) or the entire sheet row (which I don't want either).
Attached a screenshot of the right-click menu.

The same happens in the code:

```
Dim ToDelete As ListObject
Set ToDelete = Sheets("Diff").ListObjects("ToDeleteFromDL")

'Delete all rows from ToDeleteFromDL table except header
With ToDelete
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
End With
```

When I run this code, a message pops out asking "Delete entire sheet row"? To which, again, I have to answer 'Cancel', because I just want to delete the table rows.

This code used to run up to a few days ago: the only thing that comes to my mind is that there has been an update of Office installed recently.

Does anybody have the same problem or know of a issue with the update?

Thank you in advance

[[image: Right-click menu]]

Comment: Is the table filtered?

Comment: It is, but I didn't realize it immediately because the filter was on the rightmost column out of sight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Delete Excel Table's Data Body Range

```vb
With ToDelete
    If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then ' is turned on
            ' Clear existing filters.
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        'Else ' is turned off; do nothing
        End If
        ' Delete.
        .DataBodyRange.Delete xlShiftUp
    'Else ' is already deleted; do nothing
    End If
End With
```

What's with the complications?

- You cannot delete rows when the table is filtered.
- An error will occur if you use `.AutoFilter.FilterMode` when the auto filter is turned off (no arrows).
- I have tried with `xlShiftToLeft` when the whole table is gone without any warning (alert). The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.delete) states *"If this argument is omitted, Microsoft Excel decides based on the shape of the range."*. It doesn't mention Excel tables in particular. Can we trust Excel to make the right decision? Possibly but why take a chance?